# How to load contents to an existing div with jquery load() without removing the divs existing contents

Tags: php, jquery, append

I want to load the contents of a php file to an already existing div. I tried the following code, but I am getting the error load is not defined in firebug. Can some one help me?

```
 $("#post_button").click(function(){
    var result = load("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", data);
    $("#parent-post").append(result, function() {
    special_functions();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load()` is a convenience method of `$.ajax()` and by default replaces html of the selector. For more flxibility use another method like `$.get` that gives you access to return data and doesn't manipulate the DOM. You can then append instead of replace

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$("#post_button").click(function(){
    $.get("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", data, function( returnData){/* assuming your data var is data to send to server*/
            $("#parent-post").append(returnData);
            special_functions();                                                   

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably loading the remote content into a child element of the div and not the div itself.  Notice the change I made in the jquery as well (have to call load on the element you want to load the content into).

```
<div id="parent-post">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
<div id="inner_div"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#post_button").click(function(){
    $("#inner_div").load("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", 
                         data, special_functions);

 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `load` method defined here? If you are expecting it to be jQuery `load` then you should use it in this way.

```
$(element).load('url');
```

Since you want the content to be appended and not replace then `load` is the right method to use. Use any other method like `get`, `post` or `ajax` to get the content from php and then append it inside the required container.

```
$.get("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", function(response){
    $("#parent-post").append(response);
    special_functions();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", function(data){    
    $("#parent-post").append(data);        
       special_functions();

});
```

where getJSON can be $.get, $.post as well.

Answer (score 0):

here you go. Since AJAX pulls data from the server it uses an asynchronous behavior, which means that you need to give it a callback function to tell it what to do when it gets the data:

```
 $("#post_button").click(function(){
     $.post("<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/newpost.php", data, function(result) {
         $("#parent-post").append(result);
         special_functions();
      });
 });
```